# loop in R to subset from list object ( extract multiple tables from excel sheets)

Tags: r, excel, list, loops, subset

I need to extract separate tables from each excel sheet and have them as a list object. I have two lists : "allsheets" contains 38 sheets and each of sheets includes at least 2 tables, and "dataRowMeta" contains information about which rows are relevant for each table. For example,

```
 a1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1:15),y2=c(6:20))
 a2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3:18),y2=c(2:17))
 allsheets <- list(a1, a2)
 d1<- data.frame(starthead=c(1,9),endhead=c(2,10),startdata =c(3,11),
             enddata = c(7,14),footer = c(8,15))
 d2<- data.frame(starthead=c(1,10),endhead=c(2,11),startdata =c(3,12),
             enddata = c(8,15),footer = c(9,16))
 dataRowMeta <- list(d1,d2)


 [[1]]
 y1 y2
 1   1  6
 2   2  7
 3   3  8
 4   4  9
 5   5 10
 6   6 11
 7   7 12
 8   8 13
 9   9 14
 10 10 15
 11 11 16
 12 12 17
 13 13 18
 14 14 19
 15 15 20

 [[2]]
 y1 y2
 1   3  2
 2   4  3
 3   5  4
 4   6  5
 5   7  6
 6   8  7
 7   9  8
 8  10  9
 9  11 10
 10 12 11
 11 13 12
 12 14 13
 13 15 14
 14 16 15
 15 17 16
 16 18 17
```

and here is dataRowMeta :

```
 [[1]]
 starthead endhead startdata enddata footer
 1         1       2         3       7      8
 2         9      10        11      14     15

[[2]]
starthead endhead startdata enddata footer
1         1       2         3       8      9
2        10      11        12      15     16
```

I've tried to write a loop function which would subset each sheet according to dataRowMeta, but failed to get a desired output. 
I am getting an error
     `Error in sheet[[a[m]:b[m], ]] : incorrect number of subscripts`

I guess that's because I am iterating over list, not matrices...but how to tell R to subset list in this case?

So I need 1st and 4th columns of dataRowMeta(starthead and enddata) as "start" and "end" id rows of future tables.

```
tables <- function(allsheets,dataRowMeta){
for(i in 1 : length(dataRowMeta)){
  for (j in 1 : nrow(dataRowMeta[[i]])){
      a <-""
      b <- ""
    a <- dataRowMeta[[i]][j:j,1]
    b <-  dataRowMeta[[i]][j:j,4]
    for (k in 1 : length(allsheets)){
      sheet <- allsheets[k]
      for ( m in 1 : length(a)){
        tbl <-  sheet[[a[m]:b[m],]]
      }
      }
    }
  }}
```

Desired output : I have this for the first element of the first list(sheet1):

```
 sheet1 <- allsheets[[1]]
 tmp1 <- sheet1[dataRowMeta[[1]][1:1,1] :dataRowMeta[[1]][1:1,4] ,] 

 > tmp1
 y1 y2
 1  1  6
 2  2  7
 3  3  8
 4  4  9
 5  5 10
 6  6 11
 7  7 12
```

And need a loop which would do it for all sheets. Please help me to figure out how to get it. Thank you!

Comment: This is hard to understand or visualize with just code alone. Please edit and illustrate with input data and desired results without screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is my first experience with posting questions here. I've made changes you asked for, and hope it became easier to understand.